# Do I need to merge two Elasticsearch queries or can I use an or-type operator?

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have two Elasticsearch queries (which I use via the `elastic` package in R).

One query gathers the number of times a feature is loaded, the other gathers the number of times a feature is unloaded.

My needs have now changed in that I need to gather both types of data/states together, in the same dataset **(the state can either be `TRUE` or `FALSE` and I want to gather both in the same dataset)**.

**What I want to do:** To identify both cases where `visible` is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Therefore, I want to know what the best approach is: should I (attempt to) merge the queries or I should use an `or`-type operator?

If it is the latter, how would I go about it?

For completeness, here are my minified queries (unminified versions are at the end of this question):

```
loads_body <- '{"size":0,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"merchant":"a6xzTHtpQs"}},{"term":{"visible":true}},{"range":{"time":{"gte":"2018-04-02T06:00:00","lte":"2018-04-03T05:59:59","time_zone":"+00:00"}}}]}},"aggs":{"daily":{"date_histogram":{"field":"time","interval":"hour","time_zone":"+00:00","min_doc_count":0,"extended_bounds":{"min":"2018-04-02T06:00:00","max":"2018-04-03T05:59:59"}}}}}'
```

and

```
unloads_body <- '{"size":0,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"merchant":"a6xzTHtpQs"}},{"term":{"visible":false}},{"range":{"time":{"gte":"2018-04-02T06:00:00","lte":"2018-04-03T05:59:59","time_zone":"+00:00"}}}]}},"aggs":{"daily":{"date_histogram":{"field":"time","interval":"hour","time_zone":"+00:00","min_doc_count":0,"extended_bounds":{"min":"2018-04-02T06:00:00","max":"2018-04-03T05:59:59"}}}}}'
```

**Unminified queries:**

```
loads_body <- '{
    "size":0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must":[ {
                "match": {
                    "merchant": "a6xzTHtpQs"
                }
            }
            ,
            {
                "term": {
                    "visible": true
                }
            }
            ,
            {
                "range": {
                    "time": {
                        "gte": "2018-04-02T06:00:00", "lte": "2018-04-03T05:59:59", "time_zone": "+00:00"
                    }
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
    ,
    "aggs": {
        "daily": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field":"time",
                "interval":"hour",
                "time_zone":"+00:00",
                "min_doc_count":0,
                "extended_bounds": {
                    "min": "2018-04-02T06:00:00", "max": "2018-04-03T05:59:59"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

and

```
unloads_body <- '{
    "size":0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must":[ {
                "match": {
                    "merchant": "a6xzTHtpQs"
                }
            }
            ,
            {
                "term": {
                    "visible": false
                }
            }
            ,
            {
                "range": {
                    "time": {
                        "gte": "2018-04-02T06:00:00", "lte": "2018-04-03T05:59:59", "time_zone": "+00:00"
                    }
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
    ,
    "aggs": {
        "daily": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field":"time",
                "interval":"hour",
                "time_zone":"+00:00",
                "min_doc_count":0,
                "extended_bounds": {
                    "min": "2018-04-02T06:00:00", "max": "2018-04-03T05:59:59"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a single query and sub aggregations to do what you are looking for. Something along the lines of

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "match":{
                  "merchant":"a6xzTHtpQs"
               }
            },
            {
               "range":{
                  "time":{
                     "gte":"2018-04-02T06:00:00",
                     "lte":"2018-04-03T05:59:59",
                     "time_zone":"+00:00"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "Visible_agg":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"visible"
         },
         "aggs":{
            "daily":{
               "date_histogram":{
                  "field":"time",
                  "interval":"hour",
                  "time_zone":"+00:00",
                  "min_doc_count":0,
                  "extended_bounds":{
                     "min":"2018-04-02T06:00:00",
                     "max":"2018-04-03T05:59:59"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This should produce the histograms in two buckets one for "visible": true and other for "visible":false
Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you, @sramalingam24. This is almost what I'm looking for but I'm having difficulties flattening this out as it results in a dataframe consisting of two rows (true and false) and then lists of associated data stored against each row. To flatten the dataframe I use `fromJSON(toJSON(plugins_connection$aggregations$Visible_agg$buckets), flatten = TRUE)`. I think the solution is to switch around the aggregation so that the results are aggregated by date and the visibility is assigned to each instance. In short, I want to aggregate on date (histograms) in the first instance. How can I do this?

Comment: Isn't there a melt function in dataframe that will do it for you? You can try reversing the order of aggregations

Comment: I tried reversing the order of aggregations but am still left with a final column that contains lists of data which I am unable to `melt` out because: `Can't melt data.frames with non-atomic 'measure' columns`. Each list item contains a `data.frame` of 3 variables.

Comment: I was suggesting that you apply melt on solution i provided not the reversed one. I am not that familiar with python so not sure how to handle a list of dataframes

Comment: I see. I'll try that now. (FYI: `data.frame` is also a common data structure in R.)