# How do I aggregate by day for every instance across each date?

Tags: r, json, elasticsearch

I have a follow-on question from [a question I asked recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257016/do-i-need-to-merge-two-elasticsearch-queries-or-can-i-use-an-or-type-operator).

Note that I am using the Elasticsearch package (`elastic`) via R.

I want to change the aggregations in this query so that the data are aggregated by `date` and that both states of `visible` (`true` and `false`) are displayed respectively against each date value.

If more than one state applies to a single date, then I want the date to repeat. 
 Something like this:

```
          date   visible    count
1.  2018-04-01      true       10
2.  2018-04-01     false      341
3.  2018-04-02      true       10
4.  2018-04-03      true      243
5.  2018-04-03     false      495
```

How can I do this?

**Query:**

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "match":{
                  "merchant":"a6xzTHtpQs"
               }
            },
            {
               "range":{
                  "time":{
                     "gte":"2018-04-02T06:00:00",
                     "lte":"2018-04-03T05:59:59",
                     "time_zone":"+00:00"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "Visible_agg":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"visible"
         },
         "aggs":{
            "daily":{
               "date_histogram":{
                  "field":"time",
                  "interval":"hour",
                  "time_zone":"+00:00",
                  "min_doc_count":0,
                  "extended_bounds":{
                     "min":"2018-04-02T06:00:00",
                     "max":"2018-04-03T05:59:59"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using the `melt()` and `unlist()` functions but receive error messages.